# I have to show whether the groups $(\mathbb{C}, +, 0)$ and $(\mathbb{C} − \{0\}, \times, 1)$ are isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have to show whether the groups $(\mathbb{C}, +, 0)$ and $(\mathbb{C} − \{0\}, \times, 1)$ are isomorphic.

I know that two groups are isomorphic if there exists an isomorphism from one to the other. An isomorphism from $G_1$ to $G_2$ is a bijective homomorphism. We call $G_1$ and $G_2$ isomorphic, and write $G_1 \cong G_2$ if an isomorphism from $G_1$ to $G_2$ exists. I tried the following by using the lecture notes:

$\varphi:\mathbb{C}− \{0\} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$, then $x\in \mathbb{C}−\{0\}$, and $\varphi(x)\in \mathbb{C}$, then $|x|=|\varphi(x)|$. Now note that the element $i\in \mathbb{C}−\{0\}$ has order $4$. However, no element in $\mathbb{C}$ has order $4$, I think???. Hence, no isomorphism can exist. Hence, the groups $\mathbb{C}−\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are not isomorphic.

Any tips or help would be grateful!

Comment: You're on the right track when considering the order of elements.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am not sure what I am missing at this point to give a full proof.

Comment: If $\phi$ is an isomorphism and $x$ an element of finite order $n$ then $\phi(x)$ is also having a finite order equal to $n$. Is there element(s) of finite order in $(\mathbb C, +,0)$?

Comment: @TopologicalKing You're basically there. You just have to formally show that no element of $(\mathbb{C}, +, 0)$ has order $4$. By definition, an element $z \in (\mathbb{C}, +, 0)$ has order $4$ if $4z = 0$ and $kz \neq 0$ for all positive integers $k < n$.

Comment: Thankyou for your help! I appreciate it a lot!